# An error occurred while calling o127.collectToPython

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I am running a pyspark application on jupyter notebook.In some part of the code i am converting the pyspark dataframe into a pandas dataframe. 
Once i do this operation i get the below error. 
Can anyone help me in this issue.
Thanks

```
df = df.toPandas()
    py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o127.collectToPython.
: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anon$1.next(SparkPlan.scala:263)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anon$1.next(SparkPlan.scala:257)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anon$1.foreach(SparkPlan.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeCollect$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:279)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeCollect$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:278)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:278)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply$mcI$sp(Dataset.scala:2768)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2765)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2765)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2788)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:2765)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: I think your dataframe is large and can't fit into memory. Try to increase the memory or call take() method and then call toPandas()

Comment: Can you suggest which memory to increase? Is the yarn memory,executor memory,no of containers,driver memory?
It would be use full if u can share the syntax as currently i am running on jupyter notebook.

Comment: You need to increase driver memory.